# Where do I find android-server.apk?

Tags: android

I'm on a Mac 10.6.3, running Android emulator 2.3.3.  I want to run some Selenium tests on the Android app, and as such, am instructed to install the "Android WebDriver Application" using this command ...

./adb -e install -r  android-server.apk

Does anyone know where I can download the "Android WebDriver Application", aka "android-server.apk"?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1):

Go to the selenium project page. There you find it: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Comment: google code was moved to github, but I cannot find anymore the link to download the file.. could you please update your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find "android-server-2.32.0.apk" here:

```
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=android-server-2.32.0.apk&can=2&q=
```

Answer (score 0):

for android-server-2.38.0.apk

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=android-server-2.38.0.apk